# How to blend circles like this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, illustration

I’m super impressed by the smooth vector art shown in the image below.
I’m aware of the Illustrator blend tool, but I did not even get close to the desired effect.

Any tips?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

First, add objects for intermediate steps.

If you examine your sample it blends from medium > small > large > small > medium. There are 5 stages to that blend. So you need 5 objects.

Here I've shown the intermediate steps as red circles. And then created the blend. Remember **stacking order matters**. Blend stack, by default, from the top object to the bottom object. So my circles are stacked left to right, top to bottom.

[image]

Then, once you have the basic blend, you can use the **Pen Tool** to alter the spine - creating curves. You can also adjust the base objects as necessary to alter the overall shape of the blend.

Here's a horribly grainy animation (to keep the file size down) showing alteration of the blend spine....

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! However, I doubt that this technique can result in the vector art shown above. The outline is so smooth, while the eyeballing in Illustrator (in your example) will always result in not so perfect edges.

Comment: @herrvorragend To be fair.. it's not like I spent an hour getting curves exactly in position. This is merely an answer showing how to accomplish those types of blends. This was to show the **technique** and not meant to be a step-by-step tutorial resulting in your sample image. It's also feasible that your sample uses **multiple** blends stacked. based upon the circle repeats, that seems to be the case.

Comment: @herrvorragend it looks like there is some transparency going on in addition to Scott's technique. You can check to see if the blending tool can handle transparency in shapes, in addition to color.

Comment: What Scott is showing IS the actual correct way to achieve that blend. It may just take some more tweaking and blending to make it look identical. Play with it ..